# change array logic in java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I change the following code so it prints out:

> 123
>   123
>   123

instead?

```
public class A4SXYY {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a2 = new int[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a2[i].length; j++) {
                a2[i][j] = i + 1;
                System.out.print(" " + a2[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace these lines `for (int j = 0; j < a2.length; j++) { a2[i][j] = j + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a2 = new int[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a2[i].length; j++) {
            a2[i][j] = j + 1;
            System.out.print("" + a2[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

> 123

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a2 = new int[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a2[i].length; j++) {
            a2[i][j] = 3 - j;
            System.out.print("" + a2[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

> 321

Answer (score 0):

The only issue you have is in the line where you assign a value to the array. You use the are using i+1 and should be using j+1. See corrected code below:

```
public class A4SXYY{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] a2 = new int[3][3];
        for (int i=0; i<a2.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<a2[i].length; j++){
                a2[i][j] = j+1; //Use j instead of i
                System.out.print(" " + a2[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```